# PayPal Adaptive Payments IMPLICIT Pay API

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-nvp

I am basically trying to use the PAY call of Adaptive Payments to programmatically and immediately send funds from my own paypal account to other accounts. [According to the documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPayAPI), so long as I specify the senderEmail (my own paypal address, used to set up the Adaptive Payments), this should work verbatim.

However, when I make the call, I always get result "CREATED" instead of "COMPLETED". Created means the system still wants me to manually log into PayPal and approve the payments. I really need these payments to occur automatically on the spot. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my request string:

```
currencyCode=USD&
returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2F&
actionType=PAY&
cancelUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2F&
receiverList.receiver%280%29.email=receiver%40gmail.com&
receiverList.receiver%280%29.amount=1.00&
requestEnvelope.senderEmail=me%40gmail.com&
clientDetails.deviceId=mydevice&
clientDetails.ipAddress=127.0.0.1&
clientDetails.applicationId=APP-ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ&
requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&
memo=memo&
feesPayer=EACHRECEIVER&
ipnNotificationUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2Fpay.php
```

And here is the response from PayPal:

```
[responseEnvelope.timestamp] => 2012-03-01T19:09:57.290-08:00
[responseEnvelope.ack] => Success
[responseEnvelope.correlationId] => 71efd416a2100
[responseEnvelope.build] => 2486531
[payKey] => AP-ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
[paymentExecStatus] => CREATED
```

Comment: in the case mentioned above, does paypal require you to key in the password again?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Forget everything I said earlier. The problem isn't an inconsistency between Sandbox and Live either, but rather a wrong parameter for 'senderEmail'.

Simply change:

```
requestEnvelope.senderEmail=me@gmail.com&
```

To:

```
senderEmail=me@gmail.com&
```

For example, the following returns a 'COMPLETED' implicit payment.

```
<?php

function AdaptiveCall($bodyparams, $method, $payKey) {

try
{

    $body_data = http_build_query($bodyparams, "", chr(38));
    $url = trim("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/".$method."");
    $params = array("http" => array( 
                        "method" => "POST",
                        "content" => $body_data,
                            "header" => "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: xxxxxxxxx\r\n" .
                                        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: xxxxxxxxxxx\r\n" .
                                        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: xxxxxxx\r\n" .
                                        "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T\r\n" .
                                        "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV\r\n" .
                                        "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV\r\n" 
                                    )
                    );


    //create stream context
     $ctx = stream_context_create($params);


    //open the stream and send request
     $fp = @fopen($url, "r", false, $ctx);

    //get response
     $response = stream_get_contents($fp);

    //check to see if stream is open
     if ($response === false) {
        throw new Exception("php error message = " . "$php_errormsg");
     }

    //close the stream
     fclose($fp);

    //parse the ap key from the response

    $keyArray = explode("&", $response);

    foreach ($keyArray as $rVal){
        list($qKey, $qVal) = explode ("=", $rVal);
            $kArray[$qKey] = $qVal;
    }

 //print the response to screen for testing purposes
    If ( $kArray["responseEnvelope.ack"] == "Success") {
        echo "<strong>".$method ."</strong><br>";
         foreach ($kArray as $key =>$value){
        echo $key . ": " .$value . "<br/>";

    }
    // Return payKey
    global $payKey;
    if(!empty($kArray['payKey'])) { $payKey = $kArray['payKey']; return($payKey); }

     }
    else {
        echo 'ERROR Code: ' .  $kArray["error(0).errorId"] . " <br/>";
      echo 'ERROR Message: ' .  urldecode($kArray["error(0).message"]) . " <br/>";
    }

   }


catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Message: ||" .$e->getMessage()."||";
  }
}



//Create Pay body
$bodyparams = array (   "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
                        'actionType' => 'PAY',
                        'currencyCode' => 'USD',
                        'receiverList.receiver(0).email' => 'another_account@domain.tld',
                        'receiverList.receiver(0).amount' => '1.00',
                        'senderEmail' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
                        'memo' => 'Test memo',
                        'ipnNotificationUrl' => 'http://xxxxxxxx',
                        'cancelUrl' => 'http://xxxxxxxxx',
                        'returnUrl' => 'http://xxxxxxxxxx'
                    );

                    // Call Pay API
AdaptiveCall($bodyparams, "Pay");

?>
```

> **Pay response:**
>   responseEnvelope.timestamp: 2012-03-03T09%3A10%3A22.900-08%3A00
>   responseEnvelope.ack: Success
>   responseEnvelope.correlationId: 4bc5cfc4a7514
>   responseEnvelope.build: 2486531
>   payKey: AP-1XJ7636763429720C
>   paymentExecStatus: COMPLETED

Comment: Can I buy you a cup of coffee or something? =)

Comment: I am doing pretty much the same thing. But I don't know what to do with `returnUrl` and `cancelUrl`. Could we just skip them when there is no webflow?

Comment: According to PayPal "it is **always required** but only used for payments that require approval (explicit payments)", so you can use some bogus URLs

Comment: I did what you said. but didn't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329755/implicit-paypal-payment-pay-you-do-not-have-permission-to-execute-this-payme

Comment: When to call function AdaptiveCall  ..? pls help

Comment: Thanks ! It is working for me but not with the fopen it is working for me with curl.But It relay help me a lot thank you very much.