# implicit paypal payment - PAY - You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to perform an implicit payment from my account (the paypal api signed one) into another (or multiple as parallel payment).

I decided to use Adaptive Payments and have implemented the function to call the Pay action as follows

```
$bodyparams = array (
            "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
            'actionType' => 'PAY',
            'currencyCode' => 'USD',
            'receiverList.receiver(0).email' => 'receiver@domain.com',
            'receiverList.receiver(0).amount' => '1.00',
            'senderEmail' => 'myaccount@domain.com',
            'memo' => 'Test memo',
            'ipnNotificationUrl' => 'http://google.com',
            'cancelUrl' => 'http://google.com',
            'returnUrl' => 'http://google.com'
        );

        $url = "https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay";


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: XXX',
            'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: XXX',
            'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: XXX',
            'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV',
            'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON',
            'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-XXX',
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($bodyparams));

        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

        $pk="";
        if(isset($response->responseEnvelope) && $response->responseEnvelope->ack == "Success"){
            $pk = $response->payKey;
        }else{

            die(var_dump($response));
        }



        $ch = curl_init();
        header("Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=".$pk);
        die();
```

Paypal returns me  "`You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly`"

```
    {
  "responseEnvelope": {
    "timestamp": "2016-05-19T10:05:05.407-07:00",
    "ack": "Failure",
    "correlationId": "22e0930fcae7d",
    "build": "20420247"
  },
  "error": [
    {
      "errorId": "550001",
      "domain": "PLATFORM",
      "subdomain": "Application",
      "severity": "Error",
      "category": "Application",
      "message": "You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I switch the 2 accounts (i.e. just for test, the other account sends me the money), I get redirected to the approval process.

Now, the app I am using has the flag as shown in the picture below[image]

What should I check? It seems that paypal doesn't allow me to send implicit payments, but don't know for what reason (paypal support were not be able to say anything else then give me some links).

**IMPORTANT EDIT**
If I use the sandbox credentials, the payment is "`COMPLETED`"